# Rotate groups around circle Separately

Tags: jquery

I have a few smaller circles that currently rotate around a larger circle. The problem is, is that they all rotate together.

I was wondering if someone could help me with making it so that I can rotate individual ones based on a group. I cant for the life of me figure it out.

Here is the JSFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/pTGAr/4/**

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($){

!jQuery.easing && (jQuery.easing = {});
!jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad && (jQuery.easing.easeOutQuad = function( p ) { return 1 - Math.pow( 1 - p, 2 ); });

var circleController = {
create: function( circle ){
  var obj = {
    angle: circle.data('angle'),
    element: circle,
    measure: $('<div />').css('width', 360 * 8 + parseFloat(circle.data('angle'))),
    update: circleController.update,
    reposition: circleController.reposition,
  };
  obj.reposition();
  return obj;
},
update: function( angle ){
  this.angle = angle;
  this.reposition();
},
reposition: function(){
  var radians = this.angle * Math.PI / 180, radius = 600 / 2;
  this.element.css({
    marginLeft: (Math.sin( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px',
    marginTop: (Math.cos( radians ) * radius - 50) + 'px'
  });
}
};

var spin = {
circles: [],
left: function(){
  var self = this;
  $.each(this.circles, function(i, circle){
    circle.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
      { 'width': '-=45' },
      {
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        duration: 1000,
        step: function( now ){ circle.update( now ); }
      }
    );
  });
 },
right: function(){
  var self = this;
  $.each(this.circles, function(i, circle){
    circle.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
      { 'width': '+=45' },
      {
        easing: 'easeOutQuad',
        duration: 1000,
        step: function( now ){ circle.update( now ); }
      }
    );
  });
 },
prep: function( circles ){
  for ( var i=0, circle; i<circles.length; i++ ) {
    this.circles.push(circleController.create($(circles[i])));
  }
}
};

 var dataGroup;  

 $('#goL').click(function(){ spin.left() });
 $('#goR').click(function(){ spin.right() });

 $('#goLMovies').click(function(){ 

  dataGroup = "movies";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
 });

$('#goLSomething').click(function(){ 

  dataGroup = "something";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
 });

$('#goLAnimation').click(function(){ 

  dataGroup = "animation";
  spin.left(dataGroup) 
 });

spin.prep($('.circle'));

});
```

Much Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use the spin.left function like this spin.left(dataGroup) to only affect the circles with that data-group you need to add an if inside the function and compare the circle.element.data("group") with the dataGroup like this

```
var dataGroup;  
$('#goL').click(function(){ spin.left() });//spin.left all circles 
$('#goLMovies').click(function(){ 
  dataGroup = "movies";
  spin.left(dataGroup);//spin.left only movies
});    
var spin = {
    circles: [],
    left: function(group){
        var self = this;
        $.each(this.circles, function(i, circle){
            //if the circle.element data group is equal to "movies" 
            //or the dataGroup is equal to ""==all circles
            if(circle.element.data("group")==group||group==""){
                circle.measure.stop(true, false).animate(
                  { 'width': '-=45' },
                  {
                    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
                    duration: 1000,
                    step: function( now ){ circle.update( now ); }
                  }
                );
            }          
        });
    }
...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pTGAr/5/

Comment: Awesome, this works great. Apart form the 'something' group just doesn't work

Comment: that is because you have the id on the link like goLSometing not goLSomething

Comment: Thanks, never noticed that. Very tired eyes today. Thank you so much for helping me out. Very much appreciated.